# What is the difference $GPRMC and $GPRMCA?

Tags: gps, nmea

What is the difference between `$GPRMC` and `$GPRMCA` strings?

I can find [online documentation about `$GPRMC` strings](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rmc), however I have a device that sends `$GPRMCA` strings.

`$GPRMC,225446,A,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,000.5,054.7,191194,020.3,E*68`
`$GPRMCA,101959,A,0,N,0,E,0,0,20160503,,*1A`

The most obvious difference is that the day field has a different formatter (`YYYYMMDD` in `$GPRMCA` instead of the `DDMMYY` FROM `$GPRMC`)

Comment: I have never seen GPRMCA before. Which GPS device you have? If you don't have the user's manual perhaps the manufacturer can help, they tend to be friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user30184 suggested, it's not a standard.

Apparently, it's a mix of `$GPRMC` and a [Tetra location message](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100300_100399/1003921801/01.03.01_60/ts_1003921801v010301p.pdf).